# iOS Fastlane Match codesigning issue

Tags: ios, app-store, fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-gym

My xcodeproject has the signing release set as "match Adhoc *teamid*"

This works fine when building **adhoc releases**, match installs adhoc provisioning profiles and gym uses it.

But using **appstore release** match correctly installs appstore provisioning profiles ("match Appstore *teamid*") but seems gym still tries to sign with adhoc again. Giving the error:

```
error: No profile for team 'xx' matching 'match AdHoc yy' found: 
Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'xx/match 
AdHoc yy'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto 
Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab 
of the target editor. (in target 'zz')
```

my Fastfile

```
    -------adhoc part-------
    match(type: "adhoc", verbose:true)
    gym(scheme: "skoobe[Release]",
          export_method: "ad-hoc",



    -------appstore part-------
    match(type: "appstore", verbose:true)
    gym(scheme: "skoobe[Release]",
          export_method: "app-store",
```